# android support library 26.0.0-beta2 preview error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have problem with preview in android studio when using support library **26.0.0-beta2**

If I use AppCompat widgets in my layout they won't show up in the preview.

everything works fine when using  `26.0.0-beta1`.

Error text in preview window looks like this:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

I am using android studio 3 canary 5 (problem was also in canary 4). `kotlin 1.1.3` runtime and plugin. `gradle 3.0.0-alpha5` gradle wrapper `gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip` preview theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

exception shown in peview window:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Entries for a declare-styleable should be after the array declaration.
at com.android.tools.idea.res.AppResourceRepository.getDeclaredArrayValues(AppResourceRepository.java:634)
at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceClassGenerator.generateStyleable(ResourceClassGenerator.java:249)
at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceClassGenerator.generate(ResourceClassGenerator.java:120)
at com.android.tools.idea.res.ResourceClassRegistry.findClassDefinition(ResourceClassRegistry.java:102)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:101)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:215)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:215)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:214)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:336)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:155)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:225)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:90)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:325)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:151)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:297)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:382)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:591)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:739)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It didn't work for me as well, I think the beta 2 is not yet uploaded.

Comment: see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta2) it says that latest version is 26.0.0-beta2. I don't understand what's going on...

Comment: I saw that already expecting that it will work but no luck.

Comment: @Enzokie: Starting from version 25.4.0, we need to add maven repository using `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }` in build.gradle

Comment: as I said everything is working when using 26.0.0-beta1. I have Google maven repo in Gradle

Answer (score 1):

That's could be a bug. I also have experienced the same error when previewing layout with [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). I'm wasting half a day because of the bug.

Please take this bitter pill with a full heart from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta2):

> Please note that 26.0.0-beta2 is a pre-release version. Its API
>   surface is subject to change, and ***it does not necessarily include***
>   ***features or bug fixes from the latest stable versions*** of Support
>   Library.

Better stick with the stable release version until the 26.0.0 is stable enough.

Stay with [25.4.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-4-0) version because it's the latest stable version. Or use [25.3.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-3-1) to **avoid error with TabLayout** preview.

Or you can [report bugs for support library](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192731).

Answer (score 0):

Finally the new update for the support library is out, which should fix it
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0

Comment: it didn't fix it for me

Comment: What libraries, gradle version and IDE version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

i am using  26.0.0

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. After switching back to gradle 3.3 UI preview works again.
Gradle Version 3.3 
Android Plugin Version 2.3.0 
buildToolsVersion 26.0.2